# ranking function structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dense-rank

I know the DENSE_RANK() function of the ranking function and its job well. But always I only write this function’s name and it do its job implicitly can cannot see how it work explicitly and I like to see its structure which do the operations within this function with T_SQL language. Would you please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this from the execution plans.

**Example Code**

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
G INT NOT NULL,
S INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #T (G, S) VALUES (1,1),(1,1),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1)

SELECT G,S, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY G ORDER BY S) AS D
FROM #T
```

**Execution Plan**

[image]

**Description**

It first needs to sort the data in order G,S as there is no suitable index to use which is presorted.

Then there are 2 segment iterators. Segment iterators have a "GROUP BY" property. They output a *segment column* indicating whether the current row is in the same group as the previous one or not.

The first segment iterator Groups by the partitioning column G and outputs segment column Segment1004.

The second segment iterator Groups by G,S and outputs Segment1005 as the segment column.

The Sequence Project iterator outputs the `dense_rank` value based on these inputs. It will output 1 if Segment1004 indicates that this is a new partitioning group otherwise it will check the value of Segment1005 to know whether to output the same value as last time or to increment it first.

[See this article by Paul White for more](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/the-segment-and-sequence-project-iterators.aspx)